# json NullPointerException when the app is disconected

Tags: android, picasso

okay I know it has been asked a lot but I couldn't find obvious answer for my error, so please can you help.

When I dont have internet connection I get this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
```

here is where the logcat is pointing:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
```

full code

```
public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://justedhak.comlu.com/get-data.php");

            // Depends on your web service
          //  httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                File httpCacheDir = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir(),"http");
                long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
               HttpResponseCache.install(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}



protected void showList(){
    try {

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
        String[] vname = new String[peoples.length()];
        String[] vpath =new String[peoples.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);

            vname[i] = c.getString("name");
            vpath[i]=c.getString("path");
```

I am using `picasso` library and the image are cached so even if I dont have internet I want the app to open and see the cached image how to do that ?

edit php

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd,$db);

$sql = "select id, name, path from image";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('id'=>$row[0],
'name'=>$row[1],
'path'=>$row[2]
));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Means `myJSON` is `null` please share `myJSON` string also with post

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK done , and thanks for your help

Comment: problem is occurring because in response of api getting `Warning: mysql_close(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/a6901827/public_html/get-data.php on line 24` text

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I added the php script , what should I supply ?

Comment: what is line number 24?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK this `mysql_close($con);`

Comment: try to move `mysql_close($con);` before `echo` line

Comment: or try to use `mysql_close();` or see [mysql_close(): 5 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\wamp\www\Includes\footer.php on line 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054044/mysql-close-5-is-not-a-valid-mysql-link-resource-in-c-wamp-www-includes-foot)